# Questions about importing / exporting using stsadm

Tags: import, stsadm

I have 2 questions regarding stsadm -o import

1. My site has custom content types, but these are activated at site collection level. So Should I first install the WSP package on target server, then activate features prior to running an -o import command?
2. Do I need to first create a web application and site colllection on target? Prior to an import, and then assign the import url to the url of the newly created site collection? Or do I let Sharepoint create the site collection, and then manually change the address as required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right:

1. You will want to install the WSP on the target first. You may be able to get away with not activating the features, but you may as well go ahead.
2. Yes, you will want the target site collection to exist before issuing the import command.

My assumption is that you are building out a site from the WSP and then importing content after via the stsadm command?  If this is SharePoint 2010, it is preferred to use PowerShell over STSADM.